# Array index incrementing limit

Tags: c++, arrays, c

Consider the code given below. let i = 0 and size of array be 3 and for all three index it satisfy the while loop condition.so will i be keep on increasing after it has reached value of 2??

```
while (A[i] <= 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, the variable i will be increased that results in undefined behavior because there will be an access to memory beyond the array.

Comment: @ChrisMM will i be stopped ??

Comment: It depends on what is stored in the memory after the array.

Comment: Reading `A[3]` (if/when it happens) is Undefined Behaviour and you need to fix it.  Please post a [mcve] and not a code-fragment where we have to guess what values variables have been initialised with.

Comment: @Richard Critten ok i will take care next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and for all three index it satisfy the while loop condition.so will i be keep on increasing after it has reached value of 2??

Yes, it will.

Given that A[0], A[1], A[2] all are less than zero, then `i` will be increased to the value 3 and your code will try to access A[3]. That is illegal - out of array bounds - and the code has undefined behavior. That means, that we can't tell what will happen from there... The program may crash. The program may end the loop. The program may increase `i` to 4 and try to access A[4]... we can't tell

Comment: so i may go beyond 3 or it may also stop at 3.

Comment: @Abhinav1036 We know that it **will** got to 3. What happens afterwards we don't know. It may stop at 3, it may stop at 4 or it may stop at 10042... Or the program may just crash... or.... anything...

Comment: @Abhinav Note: undefined behavior (UB) includes doing something different the next time code  runs.

Comment: [Documentation for Undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). It helps if you think of code not as a list of instructions for the computer to run, but instead as a description of the behaviour you want the program to have. The compiler will take your description and produce the best list of instructions that it can come up with that will produce the behaviour. If the code includes code for which no behaviour is described by the language, the compiler won't know what instructions to produce. Usually the compiler does what it would normally do, keep looking in this case

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't do any sort of bounds checking on array accesses - it won't throw any kind of "IndexOutOfRange" exception or anything like that.  So, yes, it will keep incrementing `i` and attempting to access memory beyond the last element of the array.

Once `i` is greater than 3, the behavior is undefined and pretty much any result is allowed.  Your code may crash outright, the loop may stop at some arbitrary index `i`, `i` may overflow, or something else may happen.

When you write a loop that iterates over an array, you *must* include a condition to keep it from iterating past the end of the array, such as

```
while( i < N && A[i] <= 0 )
  i++;
```